# Leaflet labels when upgrading to 1.0.3

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-label

I try to use leaflet labels and on several pages it is successful. I wanted to use the same approach to display labels on another page and it responded with an obscure technical message which I did not understand:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.showLabel (leaflet.label-src.js:538)
    at e.showLabel (leaflet.label-src.js:287)
    at e._onMarkerAdd (leaflet.label-src.js:383)
    at e.fire (leaflet.js:5)
    at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
```

After a lot of researching I found out that leaflet.label is deprecated for Leaflet 1.0.3, which makes sense, since we are using older leaflet version in other pages where the labels appear correctly, but on the newer leaflet versions it crashes the map. The [docs](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) say that I should use `bindTooltip` instead of `bindLabel`, but I do not know how. I have tried to call it with some content on a marker but it did not appear on the map and I did not find it in the generated structure.

So, my question is as follows: How can I use labels with Leaflet 1.0.3, which will be bound to a marker and will adjust in case of translation/zoom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Tooltip](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tooltip) is indeed now directly part of Leaflet main library.

Note that it appears only on mouseover by default, but you can use the [`permanent`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tooltip-permanent) option to have it remain always visible.

```js
marker.bindTooltip("Some tooltip content", {
  permanent: true
});
```

Example: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/tiqo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you, now it does not crash the map and I can find all the labels in the structure, but they do not appear and they are positioned one below the other, regardless of the real location of the marker.

Comment: It appears on a moment and then disappears for a reason

Comment: Strange… Have you also updated the Leaflet CSS? If the bug is still there, please try to provide more details or even a live test case.

Comment: Upgrading leaflet.css was the last missing item in the puzzle. Thank you very much!